# DynamoDB Go SDK UpdateExpression won't accept a simple addition statement

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

When I do an `UpdateItem` with this expression

```
UpdateExpression: aws.String("SET ItemCount = ItemCount + 1"),
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "1", near: "+ 1"
```

The AWS SDK can't do an update with a simple addition?

I've also tried this:

```
UpdateExpression: aws.String("SET :itemCount = :itemCount + :incr"),
ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
    ":incr":  {N : aws.String("1")},
    ":itemCount": {S : aws.String("ItemCount")},
},
```

which gives this error:

```
Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: ":itemCount", near: "SET :itemCount ="
```

The item to be updated doesn't exist in the table, and I wonder if this is the problem.
The SDK would have to be smart enough to create the item and set the ItemCount attribute to 1.  The AWS docs say:

> Edits an existing item's attributes, or adds a new item to the table
> if it does not already exist.

Are the docs just wrong about this?

Answer (score 1):

ExpressionAttributeValues are just for values, there's a separate property called ExpressionAttributeNames :)

So, in pseudocode, you want either:

```
{
  UpdateExpression: "SET ItemCount = ItemCount + :inc",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {":inc": "1"}
}
```

Or:

```
{
  UpdateExpression: "SET :attr = :attr + :inc",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {":attr": "ItemCount"},
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {":inc": "1"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your original command

```
UpdateExpression: aws.String("SET ItemCount = ItemCount + 1")
```

Is that DynamoDB does not allow constants inline in the expression - instead you need to name the constant like `:inc` in your later examples, and write `SET ItemCount = ItemCount + :inc`.

The error in your second attempt is that you tried to use the named-constant syntax also for the attribute names... You don't need to (it's fine to just have the name `ItemCount` inline, but if you do, you should use the right syntax: The reference is `#attributename` (not `:attributename`) and the name appears in a ExpressionAttributeNames, not ExpressionAttributeValues.